# Installing Ubuntu on a new HDD in a Mac

Tags: software-installation, mac, usb-installation

I just recently installed a second hard drive in my late 2009 Macbook Pro. I want to boot Ubuntu from that drive. How would I go about installing it? I used UnetBootin to create a boot able USB from the iso, but how should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Update 2:

You stated you want to install Windows on the second internal disk. You did not include this in your original question. I will now add the following points.

1. A far as I know, you can not create a USB installer for any version of windows that will boot on your Mac. You must either use a DVD or Virtualization software. A DVD would be easiest. Do you know if you can boot from a Windows installation DVD using your external optical drive? If not, then you will need to download and install Virtualization software. I only have experience with VirtualBox. The download is free.
2. Installing Windows to your second internal drive requires either temporarily removing your first internal drive or creating a 100 MB partition on the first drive to hold a System Reserved partition.
3. You should first get Windows installed before we worry about installing Ubuntu. I have never owned a Mac with two internal drives, so I can advise you but I can not verify every step of the procedure.

BTW, are you sure your Macbook Pro is a late 2009 model? I ask because your model does not appear on the web page [System requirements to install Windows on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204048).

---

Update 1:

I transferred the `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` file to a USB flash drive using the current version of UNetbootin. For the "Space used to preserve files across reboots (Ubuntu only):", I used the default of 0 MB. Upon completion a window appeared as follows.

[image]

I ignored the message "The created USB device will not boot off a Mac". I assume you can also. I rebooted my computer and held down the Option key. The following menu appeared.

[image]

I chose the orange icon on the right labeled "EFI Boot". In the next menu, I selected "Check disk for defects". This took some time to complete. Upon completion, a window appeared with the message "Check finished: no errors found".

If you get this far, you can try booting to the Live version of Ubuntu. In other words, select "Try Ubuntu without installing" from the menu.

---

I did a similar install a few weeks ago. Before I post a detailed answer, I would like to know how what you want differs from what I did. I already know your second disk is internal. Mine happened to be an USB external hard drive. My computer is a iMac 20-inch Mid 2007 running OS X 10.10.3 and Windows 8.1 on the internal disk. I have rEFInd installed  as an optional boot manager. It resides in its own hfs+ formatted partition on the internal disk. I assume you would want a similar partition on your second disk.

I agree you should use UnetBootin to create the bootable USB flash drive installer. The recommended method for OS X does not verify, where as,  using UnetBootin does. I used the file `ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` which leads to an EFI/GPT install. If you are using a different iso file, let me know.

I did not install using a LVM. If you want to use a LVM or are uncertain, let me know. Also, my OS X install does not use Core Storage.

When installing Ubuntu, files were added to the EFI partition on my first disk. I moved these files to a small 100 MB hfs+ partition on the second disk. Basically, these files are GRUB. I added some files from rEFInd to make this partition appear when holding down the Option key at startup and on the Startup Disk window in the OS X System Preferences. This means all the partitions used for Ubuntu will reside only on the second disk. The second disk will contain 5 partitions. An unused 210 MB FAT formatted ESP, a 100 MB hfs+ formatted ESP, a 100 MB hfs+ formatted rEFInd partition, ext4 formatted Ubuntu partition and a Linux Swap partition.

Comment: Alright so I am using the same iso as you, and am aiming to do the same thing, which is have two separate hard drives, one for OSX, and one for Ubuntu and windows. I have the latter divided into two partitions, 500 GB a piece. I also installed rEFInd as my boot manager. After that I am kind of lost as to what you were discussing.

Comment: Additionally, when I create the usb in UnetBootin,  it tells me it will not be boot able on Mac?

Comment: @Paul: OK, what is the name of the iso file? I will download and try your file on my computer. BTW,  the recommended way is to use a DVD. Also, where (what partition) did you install rEFInd in to?

Comment: I installed it on my primary OSX boot drive. I removed my optical drive to install a second hard drive but I have a USB CD drive, will that still be effective? The iso is the same name as yours.

Comment: @Paul: I do not know if you are still interested in help. I will post how I verifed the successful creation of a USB installer. I tried this on a 2007 and 2011 iMac. If you can not replicate my results, we can try using you external optical drive. I assume it can read/write DVD's.

Comment: I am most certainly still looking for help. For some reason rEFInd isn't working now. When i boot it no longer shows up.

Comment: I usually do not install rEFInd in the OS X partition. I usually create a 100 MB partition and install rEFInd in there. In your case, I was going to suggest installing on the second disk.